# How to get specific OpenWrt subversion installed?

Tags: openwrt

I want to download OpenWRT Attitude Adjustment (12.09, r36088).

How can this be done using git ?

I tried using

```
svn co -r 36088 svn://svn.openwrt.org/openwrt/trunk
```

It downloads the packages etc and says **Checked out revision 36088** and then I run a

```
scripts/feed update -a
```

but when I type **make menuconfig**, on the top it says:

```
OpenWrt Barrier Breaker (r36085) Configuration
```

and also when I do:

```
scripts/feed search batman
```

I get no results for **batmand** and **kmod-batman-adv**. Instead I get only this result:

```
webif-batman                XWrt BATMAN mesh plugin
```

So what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `git` and `Attitude Adjustment` try to get the source like this:

```
git clone git://git.openwrt.org/12.09/openwrt.git
```

You will get the highest version of Attitude Adjustment:

```
OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment (r42647) Configuration
```

Exit from menuconfig and use `git log` to search for the revision `r36088`. You will find a commit with the id of `b812c102d1382e7073d164255ffe070b668033d4`

```
git checkout b812c102d1382e7073d164255ffe070b668033d4
```

Now check in your menuconfig again, there should be `OpenWrt Attitude Adjustment (r36088) Configuration`.

Answer (score 0):

You download Development branch, not Attitude Adjustment. Try:

```
svn co -r 36088  svn://svn.openwrt.org/openwrt/branches/attitude_adjustment
```